# How to print sum of numbers to n recursively?

Tags: python

I have written a function to print of sum of numbers to n.

```
def sumOfDigits(n):
    sum = 0
    if n < 0:
        print("Enter a positive number")
    else:
        while (n > 0):
            sum = sum + n
            n -= 1
        return sum

print(sumOfDigits(4))
```

Which prints the result fine but now i am trying to do it recursively.

```
def sumOfDigits(n):
    assert n >= 0 and int(n) == n, 'The number must be positive integer only'
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        while n > 0:
            return sumOfDigits(n) + sumOfDigits(n-1)

print(sumOfDigits(3))
```

But i am getting the following error :-

```
assert n>= 0 and int(n) == n, 'The number must be positive integer only'
   RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: A simple recursive definition for non-negative numbers: sum(0)  = 0; sum(n) = n + sum(n-1) for n > 0.

Comment: why double recursion? you only need tail recursion

Comment: Hint: if `sumOfDigits(n)` calls `sumOfDigits(n)` for some `n`, then `sumOfDigits(n)` will call `sumOfDigits(n)`, which will call `sumOfDigits(n)`, which will call `sumOfDigits(n)`, which will call `sumOfDigits(n)`,....

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Thanks for the help. I see what i am doing wrong. If you add this as an answer i will accept it.

Comment: @Brian Thanks. I got it now. Understood what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Why is this called `sumOfDigits`? It's not adding digits.

Comment: @Barmar Agreed. Sum of numbers would be a better term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In recursion, all the recursive calls must get you closer to the base case. When you call `sumOfDigits(n)`, it just repeats the same value, so it recurses infinitely.

You just need to add the current value to the recursive result, not two recursive calls. So the line

```
return sumOfDigits(n) + sumOfDigits(n-1)
```

should just be

```
return n + sumOfDigits(n-1)
```

You also don't need a `while` loop. The recursion is the loop.

```
def sumOfDigits(n):
    assert n >= 0 and int(n) == n, 'The number must be positive integer only'
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return n + sumOfDigits(n-1)
```

Your `while` loop is infinite because it never changes `n`.